# Use info from two DataFrame, differents lines, to merge in one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two Pandas DataFrame.

I'd like to obtain a new DataFrame with the files, the values and the parameters from both the file in each line.

The lines from the "first dataframe" are like:

- file_1 file_5 value1 value2

The lines from the "second dataframe" are like:

- file_1 paramA paramB
- file_5 paramX paramY

And I need something like:

- file_1 file_5 value1 value2 paramA paramB paramX paramY

(it starts with the "first dataframe" and concatenates params from the "second dataframe" for both (file_1 file_5) in the line)
And this, for each line from the "first dataframe"

I've found a solution using a loop for.
It is very **slow** (building a concatenated line, and appending it in a new DataFrame, **line by line**).

Is there some special functions that I can combine in order to perform it without looping?

My slow solution

```
for row in range(fist.shape[0]):
    file_1 = fist['file_1'][row]
    file_2 = fist['file_2'][row]
    df0 = fist.iloc[row]
    df1 = second.loc[second['FILE']==file_1,"paramA":"paramZ"]
    df2 = second.loc[second['FILE']==file_2,"paramA":"paramZ"]
    df1 = df1.add_suffix('_1')
    df2 = df2.add_suffix('_2')
    output.append(pd.concat([df0, df1, df2],axis=1))
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there input/expected data in text form (not in images) so we can copy-paste it?

Comment: It's recommended to add data as text, not as image. We can not copy the content from image.

Comment: Done, sorry.
I've tried to use "table" format, but it was ok before submitting the message (the image was a screenshot) and not ok after submitting.
I've changed the way to present it, in text

Answer (score 1):

df1 and df2 are two pandas dataframes.

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1)
```